# ImportError: cannot import name 'array2d'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Code:

```
from sklearn.utils.validation import array2d
```

Output:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'array2d'
```

I have installed sklearn v0.23.1 with pycharm.

I tried to look in `site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py` and find "array2d" with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, but it is not there. Can I import something when it is not in the file?

I am not sure, if the problem is in installation or import.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils) of the latest stable version (currently 0.23.1), there is **no** module `array2d` in `sklearn.utils.validation`.

The situation is the same for the previous versions [0.22.2](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils), [0.21.3](https://scikit-learn.org/0.21/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils), [0.20.4](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils), [0.19.2](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils), and [0.18.2](https://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.utils).

Not sure where you got this from and what you are trying to do - googling the error leads to [this closed Github thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4272), where the usage is not like the one you try here (and the error there comes from a broken installation, which is certainly not the case here).

In short, the command `from sklearn.utils.validation import array2d` is **invalid**, and the error thus justified.